# Merging files within a subfolder for a large batch of subfolders

Tags: python

I am analyzing some data in a bioinformatics pipeline (qiime). I am trying to use a cat command to merge two files within a subfolder - I need to do this for 330 files, but am having trouble with the command string.

My current string:

```
cat AdapterRemoval/*.fastq/output_paired.collapsed AdapterRemoval/*.fastq/output_paired.collapsed.truncated > AdapterRemoval/*.fastq/mergedfile.fastq
```

This is the code I am using - with the * to indicate the command should look in all .fastq folders for the files output_paired and output_paired.collapsed then merge those files into one mergedfile.fastq and place it within the same folder the original files are found in.

For instance:

```
AdapterRemoval/C1.fastq/output_paired.collapsed AdapterRemoval/C1.fastq/output_paired.collapsed.truncated > AdapterRemoval/C1.fastq/mergedfile.fastq
```

So that those two files found within the AdapterRemoval/C1 subfolder would be merged and the merged file placed in that same subfolder.

In fact, when I type it out like this using the single filepath with a specific folder ID, it works. But when I put the * in place of the subfolder I get an error saying there is no such directory or file as AdapterRemoval/*.fastq/mergedfile.fastq

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you,

Sarah

Comment: Have you tried to use the function [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.walk)? It returns the whole file tree from one folder downwards.

Comment: Sven - Thank you for the suggestion, I will try this and see if it works. Also, thank you to Rakesh for the editing suggestion, my code is much easier to read in that format.